# NHibernate LINQ 3.0 Oracle Expression type 10005 is not supported by this SelectClauseVisitor

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, distinct

I have the following LINQ query

```
    QueryResult<List<PersonDemographic>> members = new QueryResult<List<PersonDemographic>>();

    var query = (from ms in this.Session.Query<MemberSummary>()
                 where ms.NameSearch.StartsWith(firstName.ToUpper())
                    && ms.NameSearch2.StartsWith(lastName.ToUpper())
                 select new PersonDemographic
                 {
                     FirstName = ms.FirstName.ToProperCase(),
                     LastName = ms.LastName.ToProperCase(),
                     PersonId = ms.Id,
                     Address = new Address
                     {
                         Line1 = ms.AddressLine1.ToProperCase(),
                         Line2 = ms.AddressLine2.ToProperCase(),
                         City = ms.City.ToProperCase(),
                         State = ms.State,
                         Zipcode = ms.Zipcode,
                     },
                     PhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber
                     {
                          Number = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ms.PhoneNumber) ? null : Regex.Replace(ms.PhoneNumber, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "$1-$2-$3")
                     }
                 });

    if (this.Session.Transaction.IsActive)
    {
        members.Data = query.Distinct().Take(15).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        using (var transaction = this.Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            members.Data = query.Distinct().Take(15).ToList();                    
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

The code is running under the transaction section. If I use it without a Distinct I have no problem. Adding the Distinct gives me an exception

{"Expression type 10005 is not supported by this SelectClauseVisitor."}

I can't find anything definitive. Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things in that query that NH can't possibly know how to translate to SQL:

- ToProperCase (that looks like an extension method of yours)
- string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (that's new in .NET 4, NH is compiled against 3.5)
- Regex.Replace (that's just not possible to do with SQL, unless you have a DB that supports it and write a Dialect for it)

Comment: Diego, I didn't think the assignments would have any effect but hey, ya never know. So I removed eveything that you had mentioned and I still get the same exact error. One thing I did forget to mention is that thi sis hitting a view, not a table. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I just upgraded to NHibernate 3.1 and now the exception is Expression type 'NhDistinctExpression' is not supported by this SelectClauseVisitor.

Comment: @PaulSperanza: the message is better, the error is still the same: you are trying to mix client-side and server-side operations. I suggest you remove all the expressions I mentioned and try again.

Comment: I stripped every transform action out. What it does not like is my PersonDemographic object. This object is a DTO with no functionality.